# How to use Matplotlib to Plot Live Data with Timestamp

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, plot

I'm trying to live plot a 3 element vector against time. I have code which is constantly churning out Euler angles (roll, pitch, and yaw), and I'm trying to see how the values change over time with the clock constantly running (timestamp).

Ultimately, I'm trying to get a 3 element vector/ list to plot against time (on the x-axis). So with every second that passes, this is the 3 element value - kind of thing.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I get a straight vertical line with no change. I also (previously) got the error(I'm assuming for time only being 1 element):

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (3,)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from random import randint
import time
import numpy as np

Time = time.time()

fig = plt.figure()

x = []
y = []
def animate(i):
    while True:
        n  = randint(1,1000)
        n1 = randint(1,1000)
        n2 = randint(1,1000)
        euler = [n, n1, n2]
        
        x.append(Time)
        y.append(euler)
    
    
        return plt.plot(x, y, color='r')

       
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never update the time. You get `Time` before you enter the animate function, and you always use that value. Try something like `x.append(time.time())`. The other issue that you have is that plot likes x to be a 1D array and y to be a 1D array as well. Use three different arrays instead of `euler` and just plot them on the same figure